# SQLAlchemy inserting data into two tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am just working on my first App based on SQLAlchemy and after couple hours of work with the documentation and some videos, I still can't fix the issue.

My app is a simple CRUD grocery list. I want to keep the category of the product in separate table so here comes relationship module of the SQLAlchemy. Error msg gives me no hint at all tbh.

```
engine = create_engine(my_database, echo = True)

connection = engine.connect()

Base = declarative_base()
session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

class MyEnum(enum.Enum):
    one = "pieces"
    two = "kg"

class ProductTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    product_quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    product_type = Column(Enum(MyEnum), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    category = relationship("category", back_populates="product")
    product_description = Column(String(255))


class CategoryTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_name = Column(String(25), nullable=False)

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

session = session()

cc_product = ProductTable(product_id=1,
                          product_name="cucumber",
                          product_quantity="1",
                          product_type="kg",
                          product_description="For the salad")

cc_category= CategoryTable(category_name="vegetables")


session.add(cc_product, cc_category)

session.commit()
```

I. Creation of the tables finished smoothly with no errors, however, is the creation itself designed properly? Each product has single category but one category should be assigned to one or more product. I made that based on one to one relationship.

II. Inserting data to both tables. I want to insert data like:

1. Product_id = 1
2. Product_name = Cucumber
3. Product_quantity = 1
4. Product_type = "kg" or "pieces"
5. Category = Vegetables ( from the category table)
6. Description = "blah blah blah"

I think there is something wrong not only with the data inserting process but also with the tables creation.

Here is the error, which tbh, doesn't tell me anything:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: relationship 'category' expects a class or a mapper argument (received: <class 'sqlalchemy.sql.schema.Table'>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ArgumentError: relationship expects a class or mapper argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25002620/argumenterror-relationship-expects-a-class-or-mapper-argument)

Comment: You have some small errors, like passing [`Session.add()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.add) multiple instances as arguments (the second will not be added actually), using the wrong target in the relationship, which trips mapper configuration, and using `back_populates` without defining the other end (instead of `backref`). The product and category are not linked either. I'd recommend (re)reading the [ORM tutorial](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/tutorial.html).

Comment: I found some minor errors, about Session.add() and the fact, that these tables aren't actually linked but I just lack with the idea how to set them correctly. The documentation is great but since it's referring to so many different concepts at the same time, I am so confused. If there is anyone, who could describe how this relationship for this specific case should look like, i would highly appreciate that

Comment: Instead of trying to form a relationship to the `Table` (the name you've given in the model with `__tablename__`), create a relationship to the model: `relationship("CategoryTable", ...)`. And with the linking I meant that you should for example do `cc_product.category = cc_category` before commit.

Comment: @IljaEverilä like that?:                                                                   `category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('product.product_id'))` and `categories = relationship("CategoryTable",backref='product')`

Comment: Yes on the latter, but why `ForeignKey('product.product_id')`? Leave `category_id` as it was.

Answer (score 0):

You have two mistakes:

1. you wrote `"category"` as the Mapper class instead of `"CategoryTable"`
2. forgot to create products on 'CategoryTable'

```
class ProductTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'product'
    product_id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    product_name = Column(String(30), nullable=False)
    product_quantity = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    product_type = Column(Enum(MyEnum), nullable=False)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    categories = relationship("CategoryTable", back_populates="products")
    product_description = Column(String(255))


class CategoryTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    category_name = Column(String(25), nullable=False)
    products = relationship('ProductTable', back_populates='categories')
```

Some more changes are still needed:

- change `CategoryTable` to `Category` (also for `ProductTable`, better names)
- you'll have constraints failing after you'll get things running...

Comment: I have manged to make it up and running by doing it this way: https://pastebin.com/k1j0KRAM Even though I don't exactly understand why but it works..